# 通報を間違えてしてしまったかもしれない

Tags: 討議

現在、私が投稿した質問に回答が付きましたが、その回答に対してコメントしようとしたときにサイトの反応が遅く2,3回ほどマウスクリックを連打してしまった時マウスカーソルが一瞬「通報」のところにホバーしました。
そしてその時は私のブラウザが重かったというのもあって一瞬だけサイトの挙動がおかしくなり、
そのときにもしかしたらその回答を通報してしまったかもしれませんでした。
そして後に自分のプロフィールを見ると獲得したことのない「自警団」のバッチが付与されています。

大変良い回答でしたのでもし間違えて通報してしまっていた場合回答者様に申し訳無さすぎると思ったので質問させていただきました
もし今回の通報が私の勘違いによるもので、実際は通報されていなかったとしても今後この様な自体が起きるかもしれないので、この様な場合はどの様なこちらの対応をすれば良いのか教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: バッジ付与日時が今日ではなかったので勘違いでした。すみません。
しかし質問文にもある通り間違えてやってしまった場合の対処法を教えてくれると嬉しいです。何かこちらが出来ることはありますか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

通報のリンクをクリックした場合、実際には理由を選択するポップアップが表示されます。

[投稿の通報 - ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

また、ユーザーは自分自身のプロフィールページから通報履歴を確認できますが、今回気にされている通報は行われていないようです。

---

「通報」という表現が少し仰々しいので身構えてしまいますが、元の英語では Flag となっており、主にモデレーターに対して注意を促すための機能となっています。

通報のフラグが立った場合には、必ず内容を確認してから実際のアクションを決定しているので、(間違いだった場合を含めて) 通報を行った時点で直ちに相手にマイナスになるような事態にはなりませんので安心してください。通報した本人に対しても (極端なケースを除いて) 1, 2回程度の間違い通報では特にペナルティ等はありません。